# Keras ImageDataGenerator() how to get all labels from data

Tags: python, keras

I am using the ImageDataGenerator() in Keras and I would like to get the labels of my entire test data.

Currently I am using the following code to accomplish this task:

```
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(...)

test_labels = []

for i in range(0,3):
    test_labels.extend(np.array(test_batches[i][1]))
```

This code however only works because I know I have a total of 150 images and my batch size is defined to be 50.

Moreover using:

```
imgs, labels = next(test_batches)
```

as suggested in similar posts on this topic only returns labels for one batch and not the entire dataset. As such I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this than the method I am using above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well - when you know the `batch_size` you could obtain number of images from `flow_from_directory` object:

```
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(.., batch_size=n)
number_of_examples = len(test_batches.filenames)
number_of_generator_calls = math.ceil(number_of_examples / (1.0 * n)) 
# 1.0 above is to skip integer division

test_labels = []

for i in range(0,int(number_of_generator_calls)):
    test_labels.extend(np.array(test_batches[i][1]))
```

Comment: how to get them if I have a pair of images as input and generator is constructed in a way shown [here](https://gist.github.com/RyanAkilos/3808c17f79e77c4117de35aa68447045#gistcomment-3439342)

Answer (score 17):

You can simply get a dictionary from the DirectoryIterator containing both the labels and the index in the one-hot encoding. Accessing the keys will then give you all the labels.

```
test_batches.class_indices.keys()
```

Answer (score 7):

If you just wants the labels, you can directly use

```
test_batches.labels
```

But some times you want the value, then you can do like this: 
    validation_x = []

```
for i in range( test_batches.__len__() ):
    validation_x.extend(
        test_batches.__getitem__( i )[0] 
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that the `flow` method allows for passing both the images and the labels. But you need to have your images already loaded in memory.

I never tried that with `flow_from_directory`, but if you look at the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) it seems that they ask you to have a main directory and a subdirectory for each label.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way to obtain the one-hot encoded labels from the ImageDataGenerator()

```
test_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(test_batches.labels, num_classes=CLASS_SIZE)
```